# Calculate Specificity and sensitivity from AUC

Tags: roc, auc, confusion-matrix, sensitivity-specificity

Can someone please tell me how you calculate Specificity and sensitivity from AUC?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single sensitivity (or specificity) value associated with a particular ROC curve's AUC.

We define an ROC curve using a range of true positive rate (sensitivity) values and their associated false positive rate. Therefore the value of the ROC-AUC does not imply a particular sensitivity (or specificity) value. There are some heuristics for selecting the optimum cut-off point for a ROC curve (e.g. the [Youden index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic)) and that cut-off point will correspond to a unique value of sensitivity (and it's respective specificity) but once more that will not map uniquely to that ROC curve's AUC.

Comment: ROC curves, sensitivity, and specificity are at odds with how decisions are made, as they are all based on backwards-in-time conditional probabilities.  So it’s not clear why you are interested in them.